# How to activate an item dynamically on navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar

I have 4 pages that refer to each other on a navbar (index2.html/seite1, seite2, seite3.html).
I'm trying to find a page to highlight the current page on the navbar, but I only manage to do it for a split second. It turns red when I click but immediately to the default "Home".
I've been stuck on this for days and I can't find the problem. Is there a loop on the  tag that I don't see? Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<style>
.navbar-dark .nav-item > .nav-link.active  {
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div>

    <nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" style="padding-left: 0px;" href="index2.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="seite1.html">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="seite2.html">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="seite3.html">Page 3</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
        

<script> 

$('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function(){
    $ ('.navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

})  


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is just HTML without any server-side rendering, then you have 4 different HTML files.  In the Home page, only the home tab must have active class, in seite1 page only the seite1 tab must have the active class,..etc

Comment: I'm just studying about it... thanks for the help, it worked fine!